# Firefox extension for total page size?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Does anybody know a good Firefox extension to monitor the total page size, including all supplementary files. I know there is one that monitors the viewstate size in the bottom bar and that's invaluable as an ASP.Net developer, but I wonder it there's one that monitors the entire size--sort of like the Net tab of Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Extended Statusbar extension that does what I wanted. It has speed, size, etc. very simply in the bottom bar.

Answer (score 2):

The web developer toolbar does this with two clicks:

Information -> View Document Size

And it has a ton of other handy features!

Comment: Does the web developer toolbar show what was already in the browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) works great for me (have a look at the statistics tab).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else shows up here searching for "firefox extension page weight" because it was not obvious where to look in the built-in Web Developer Tools, it is in fact where we should expect.

Network tab, like everything under the Network tab you have to, after opening it, "Perform a request or `Reload` the page to see detailed information about network activity."

**Important:** First checkmark "Disable Cache" (towards the right on the line below the primary tabs selection) or you will get [inaccurate results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ9Sw.png).

Once you have disabled cache and reloaded, make certain you have "All" selected (next line below that, at the left) to get the total page weight, in the grey status bar which is *below* all the individual requests.  It is not a line like those but rather starts with the performance analysis watch (which we do not have to press for this) and then lists:

- Number of requests
- Total amount (size) of data (the page weight we're looking for) / data transferred on this request
- Time to finish downloading, and a couple more time-based basic performance stats (all can be hovered over for a bit more explanation)

[image: A screenshot of Firefox's Web Developer Tools switch to the Network tab, 'Disable Cache' checked on the next line to the right, and 'All' selected on the line below that to the left, after network measurement has been enabled, showing 21 requests and 778.03kB / 52/.80 kB transferred.]

If you filter network tab by JS, Images etc the totals at the bottom will show you the amount only for that type of asset.